# What is the networking.service?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, network-manager, services

I'm learning **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and i confuse between `networking.service`, `NetworkManager.service` and `systemd-networkd.service`.
After googling i found that `NetworkManager.service` and `systemd-networkd.service` are two way to manage the network and we only need 1 of them. No result for `networking.service`.

I already tested on **Ubuntu 16.04** **Desktop** and **Server**. On desktop `NetworkManager.service` and `networking.service` are active, on server only `networking.service` active. I don't understand what `networking.service` is? 
Could you help me please?

Comment: The `networking` service just brings up the network devices. Network Manager actually manages them on desktops, and on servers they maybe be managed via `/etc/network/interfaces` or `systemd-networkd`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`networking.service` raises or downs the network interfaces configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`, that is, those network interfaces which are *not* managed by NetworkManager. If you look into `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service` you will see that all it does is `ifup` or `ifdown` depending on whether it is to be started or stopped.

It is a oneshot unit, which means that it does its thing and exits, it does not remain running in the background.

By default all network interfaces are managed by NetworkManager and `networking.service` does nothing. On a server it is quite common to assign a static IP address to one or more interfaces by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`, and in this case those interfaces are no longer managed by NetworkManager and they are raised or downed by `network.service`.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. I installed Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and only networking.service is active, NetworkManager.service and systemd-networkd.service are not. So that mean we don't need them on Ubuntu Server right?

Comment: The server installer places all network interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`, which means that their activation is performed by `network.service`. At least all _wired_ interfaces -- I have never used the server variant of Ubuntu on a computer with WiFi.

Comment: Isn't `networking.service` responsible for bringing up the loopback interface (even where all external interfaces are managed by NetworkManager)?

Comment: @AlexP **NOTE**, that OP is asking about `networkd.service`. `networking.service` and `networkd.service` are two different things. The `networking.service` does what you describe - executing `ifup` & `ifdown` but `networkd.service` is actually replacement for `ifupdown` package designed around `systemd`.

Comment: @dtoubelis: Note that this question was asked and answered in 2016.

Comment: If the `network.service` failed - can I stop it and disable it? When?

Comment: @pbies: Better find out why it failed. It shouldn't fail.

Comment: @AlexP `/etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail: 44: .: Can't open /usr/share/sendmail/dynamic
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail exited with return code 2`

Comment: @AlexP I've removed sendmail `sudo apt purge sendmail sendmail-base sendmail-bin` but other error appeared...

Comment: @pbies: I'm sorry, this is not suitable forum for technical support.